# php csv generator not outputting file, multiple select not passing values

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, csv

I am building a CSV generator that takes a selection of areas from a multiple select box and loops through the selected to pop out a separate CSV for each item based on database info, or at least it is supposed to, it keeps popping out a PHP file with my header include and then an error about an undefined $filename variable once for each item I have selected, it does not pass the Area_ID at all from the multiple select. Another oddity (at least as far as I can see, probably normal but seems odd to me) is that the CSVGen function if included from a separate file requires my database connect string inside the function where the page that calls it has my DB connect include present, seems impractical to open up to 2 dozen new sessions instead of using the one I've already opened.

Here is the main page:

```
<?php
$page_title="CSV Generator";
include("\Include\header.inc");
include("\Include\connect-db.php");
include("\Include\CSVGen.php");

$error="";

$start_date=date("Y-m-d");
$end_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 days"));


if(isset($_GET['reg'])) 
{
    $reg=$_GET['reg'];
}

else{
    $reg='1';
}


if($start_date>$end_date){
    $error = 'ERROR: End Date cannot be before Start Date!';
}

if ($error != '')

{

echo '<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-12">'.$error.'
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>';

}
        $sqlareas="SELECT Area_Name, Region_ID FROM Listings_Areas WHERE region = '$reg'";
        $arearesult= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlareas, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
        $areacount = sqlsrv_num_rows($arearesult);


function renderForm($arearesult, $areacount, $start_date, $end_date){
?>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">

        <p><select name="arealist[]" size="<?php echo $areacount ;?>" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">

        <?php

        while($areas=sqlsrv_fetch_array($arearesult)){
        echo'<option value="' . $areas['Area_ID'] . '">' . $areas['Area_Name'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">   
        <strong>Start Date: </strong> <input type="date" name="start" value="<?php echo $start_date; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">  
        <strong> End Date: </strong> <input type="date" name="end" value="<?php echo $end_date; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">  
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get CSVs">
    </div>
    </form>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
<?php
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$start_date=$_POST['start'];
$end_date=$_POST['end'];
$areasselect=$_POST['arealist'];

foreach($areasselect as $selected){
$area_id = $selected;

//echo $area_id . $start . $end;

CSVGEN($area_id, $start_date, $end_date);

}
}

else {renderForm($arearesult, $areacount, $start, $end);}

?>
</div>
```

And here is CSVGen.php, I built it standalone originally for testing (where it worked fine), so there are some commented out sections to pull variables from URL.

```
<?php
// connect to db
function CSVGen($area_id, $start_date, $end_date){

include("\Include\connect-db.php");
//if (isset($_GET['area']) && is_numeric($_GET['area']) && $_GET['area'] > 0)

//{ 
//    $area_id = $_GET['area'];
//    $start_date = $_GET['start'];
//    $end_date = $_GET['end'];

// fetch the data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Listings WHERE area_id ='$area_id' AND date >=convert(datetime, '$start_date') And date <=convert(datetime,'$end_date')";
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$prev_program = "";
$i=0;
$csv= array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results)) {
        $program=$row['name'];
        $date=$row['date'];
        $start=$row['time_start'];

        $programclean = str_replace("'","''", $program);

        //echo 'area id ' . $area_id . ' / program ' . $program . ' / date ' . $date . ' / start time ' . $start . '<br>';
        if($prev_program!=$program){
        $sql2= "SELECT Area_Name, Region_ID FROM Listings_Areas WHERE Area_ID = '$area_id'";
        $results2= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2);
        $row2= sqlsrv_fetch_array($results2);
        $filename=$row2['Area_Name'] . ' Eastlink TV.csv';
        $station_ID = $row2['Region_ID'];
        //echo 'station ID ' . $station_ID . ' / Filename ' . $filename . '<br>';

        $sql3 = "SELECT PID, description, DUR, GENRE, TYPE FROM pid WHERE Title='$programclean'";
        $results3= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql3);
        $row3=sqlsrv_fetch_array($results3);

        if($row3){

        $PID=$row3['PID'];
        $gendesc=$row3['description'];
        $gendur=$row3['DUR'];
        $genre=$row3['GENRE'];
        $subgenre=$row3['TYPE'];

        //echo '<br>pid ' . $PID . ' / gendesc ' . $gendesc . ' / gen duration ' . $gendur . ' / genre ' . $genre . ' / subgenre ' . $subgenre . '<br>';
        }
        $sql4 = "SELECT EID FROM asdb WHERE airdate='$date' AND PID='$PID'";
        $results4 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql4);

        if($rows=sqlsrv_has_rows($results4)==true){
            $row4=sqlsrv_fetch_array($results4);
            $EID=$row4['EID'];

            $sql5 = "SELECT Description, DUR FROM eid WHERE EID='$EID'";
            $results5= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql5);

            if($rows=sqlsrv_has_rows($results5)==true){
                $row5=sqlsrv_fetch_array($results5);
                $desc=$row5['Description'];
                $dur=$row5['DUR'];
            }
        }
        else{
            $sql6 = "SELECT EID, PID, Description, DUR FROM eid WHERE LIST_Title='$programclean'";
            $results6= sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql6);

            if($rows=sqlsrv_has_rows($results6)==true){
                $row6=sqlsrv_fetch_array($results6);
                $PID=$row6['pid'];
                $desc=$row6['description'];
                $dur=$row6['DUR'];
            }
        }

        if(empty($gendesc)){$gendesc=$program;}
        if(empty($desc)){$desc=$gendesc;}

        if(empty($gendur)){$gendur="30";}
        if(empty($dur)){$dur=$gendur;}

        $start_time=date("H:i", strtotime($start));
        $end_time=date("H:i", strtotime("+".$dur." minutes", strtotime($start)));
        $date= date("m/d/y", strtotime($date));

        $csv[$i]['Station ID']=$station_ID;
        $csv[$i]['Program Start Date']=$date;
        $csv[$i]['Program Start Time']=$start_time;
        $csv[$i]['Program End Time']=$end_time;
        $csv[$i]['Duration']=$dur;
        $csv[$i]['Program Title']=$program;
        $csv[$i]['Program Description (optional)']=$desc;
        $csv[$i]['Category']=$genre;
        $csv[$i]['Sub Category']=$subgenre;
        $csv[$i]['Time Zone?']='Atlantic';
        $csv[$i][]="\r\n";

        }
        $prev_program = $program ;
        unset($gendesc, $desc, $dur, $gendur, $end, $end_time, $start, $start_time);
        $i++;
}


// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='" . $filename . "'");

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Station ID', 'Program Start Date', 'Program Start Time', 'Program End Time', 'Duration', 'Program Title', 'Program Description (optional)', 'Category', 'Sub Category', 'Time Zone?' . "\r\n"));

// loop over the rows, outputting them
foreach ($csv as $line) {
                fputcsv($output, $line);
}

fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");
}
?>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what my glaring mistake is here, I've been getting frustrated at this for the last couple of days...

EDIT: I have realized one of my glaring mistakes, This:

```
$sqlareas="SELECT Area_Name, Region_ID FROM Listings_Areas WHERE region = '$reg'";
```

should have been:

```
$sqlareas="SELECT Area_Name, Region_ID, Area_ID FROM Listings_Areas WHERE region = '$reg'";
```

Now I have only the problem that it's spitting out a single CSV (properly named for the first area selected) with my header file followed by the data for all selected areas instead of a separate file for each without the header file that I can't figure out why it's printing at all. I really don't need to send CSVs with my navbar code at the top...

Comment: start by setting in your main page error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); and examine the errors

Comment: have you tested whether $areasselect actually contains anything in your first file?  Also, have you tried outputting each area id in your foreach loop to make sure the data is being captured before you call your csv generator?

Comment: I have tested whether $areasselect has anything, hence the echos within the loop and var_dump that I had removed and as far as I can tell it contains nulls instead of the values it should, even though I've followed the examples I've found elsewhere in writing a multiple select to an array.

Comment: have you tried looping through the POST value itself, instead of assigning it to a variable first:  foreach($_POST['arealist'])

Comment: have you had a peek at your developer's console to check that the ids that you select are indeed being sent in the posted data?

Comment: That part is fixed now, see the edit at the bottom of my post where I show what my stupid mistake was (knew I'd made one somewhere). now my only issue is trying to get more then 1 CSV at a time and that it's including my navbar code in the CSV it is making.

Comment: After indenting your code in an editor, it appears that your code to create a file is not in a loop, which means it is only going to create one file.  If you want more than one csv, it will need to be in a loop.  That loop will need some code that creates each file and saves them somewhere on the server. After the loop you would then redirect the user to a page with links to their generated files.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is a so-called "conditional declaration".

In the while-loop is an if-statement in which the variable $filename is created/assigned (!). When the loop is started and the if-conditions is NOT met, $filename is undefined because the if-case code was never executed.

Once defined, it will keep its last assignement until the if-condition is met again. It is basically a group-break you have programmed, wether by intention or not, but you have missed an important fact: Your data must be ordered, otherwise group-break will not work correctly.

You should start to debug your code to understand its workflow. Remove the conditional declaration by initializing variables first.

And you should rethink your coding style, the indention is extremely hard to read, especially since you mix it...

Comment: The indentation is much better in the code itself, it messed up in the copy/paste here and I was unaware of ctrl-k until after I posted, but you are correct, my coding style is not particularly good, this is the first time I have coded outside of a single course 10+ years ago which was entirely in VB and the only time I have ever used PHP, HTML, or SQL.

As for the conditional declaration, it works if the CSV generator is passed the correct variables (Area_ID is not passing which is causing the break) if I initialize the variables it can't name the file based on area which changes each run.